# How to get data from apps when upgrading to iOS 5 on an iPad 2

Tags: itunes, applications, ios, windows, ipad

I updated my iPad 2 to iOS 5 using my Windows PC.

I backed up my apps, calendar, mail, photos, etc. using iTunes before the iOS 5 update. However, although I got my apps, I am missing all the data in them! For instance: for iAnnotate PDF I am missing all my annotated files, in Note Taker HD I am missing all my notes, and most importantly in bizXpensTrkr I am missing all my business receipts and data!

Can someone please advise in layman's terms? I am new to Apple and used a PC to update.

Comment: Did you choose to restore your backup after upgrading?

Answer (score 1):

Do you still have your backup?

Connect your iPad, right click it in iTunes' sidebar and select restore from backup (Sometimes it helps to restore from backup twice).

Comment: I have this same problem but as soon as i plugged my iPad in to back it up, it backed up again and wouldnt let me do anything else. is there a way to restore to an older backup?